# What is the modulus of the glibc pRNG LCG?

Tags: c, random, glibc, ansi-c, lcg

I'm a bit confused at the moment about the linear congruential generator used in the rand() function in stdlib to generate random numbers. The table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator lists the modulus used by GCC and for ANSI C as 2^31. However, according to https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf p347, for ANSI C 2^32 is implicitly used. Does rand() in stdlib also use 2^32?

I've implemented and tested the ANSI C implementation, which works fine.

Comment: I think the compiler itself doesn't generate random numbers, so are you talking about the standard C library that GCC links your program with?  What platform are you targeting with GCC and what C library are you using?

Comment: Yeah I mean glibc used by GCC. So the main question is which modulus the rand() function provided by stdlib uses, on unix.

Comment: So you're asking about the `rand()` function provided glibc, the GNU C library. I suggest updating your question to reflect that.

Comment: Note that the code in the ANSI/ISO C standard is only a sample implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Glibc, `rand` (defined in [rand.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/rand.c;h=30caa49e21cc6644bba68ef63b51b68813a4b1ff;hb=9d94997b5f9445afd4f2bccc5fa60ff7c4361ec1)).
is a just a wrapper for `__random`.  And `__random` (defined in [random.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;h=6da39d45a347ca90078da85582e9a231378e79cd;hb=9d94997b5f9445afd4f2bccc5fa60ff7c4361ec1) is just a wrapper for `__random_r`.    And `__random_r` (defined in [random_r.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;h=b6297fe099af9af238caaebb9c21764e9360812b;hb=9d94997b5f9445afd4f2bccc5fa60ff7c4361ec1#l353)) has two different code paths, but I think the relevant one is this one:

```c
     int32_t val = ((state[0] * 1103515245U) + 12345U) & 0x7fffffff;
     state[0] = val;
     *result = val;
```

Comment: Looks like Glibc uses 2^31, good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Even with `& 0x7fffffff` as part of `rand()`, `state[0]` may be more than `0x7fffffff` due to `srand()`.  IAC, the modulus rapidly devolves into 2^31 when `buf->rand_type == TYPE_0`.

Comment: Jup, I was only looking into the simple LCG implementation.